# How to get the ApplicationPool object based on a Site in IIS

Tags: c#, iis, servermanager

I've created an application that gets all of my Sites in IIS and checking each URL in Bindings if there's an HTTP error and if a certain error is encountered, my application will reset the IIS Site Instance in IIS, however, it's not enough to fix the error as it should. I would be needing to reset **both the Site and the Application pool it belongs to.**

Is there any way to get the Application Pool object based on the Site object?

I have tried the code below but this only works if an application pool only has 1 Site/Application in it. The problem is, I don't get the matching App Pool of the Site if I have a number mismatch between the List of Sites vs List of ApplicationPools since 1 AppPool can have multiple Sites/Applications.

```
ServerManager serverMgr = new ServerManager();
SiteCollection sites;
ApplicationPoolCollection appPools;
public List<(Site, ApplicationPool, string)> getSiteInfo()
{
    List<(Site, ApplicationPool, string)> siteInfo = new List<(Site, ApplicationPool, string)>();
    List<string> siteUrls = new List<string>();
    sites = serverMgr.Sites;
    appPools = serverMgr.ApplicationPools;
    foreach (Site site in sites)
    {
        foreach (ApplicationPool appPool in appPools)
        {
            foreach (Binding binding in site.Bindings)//getting site url
            {
                string bindingInfo = binding.BindingInformation; // "192.111.1.1:80:google.com" /// *:808:
                string[] adrs = bindingInfo.Split(':'); //0 = ip, 1 = port, 2 = hostname
                if (adrs[0] == "*")
                {
                    adrs[0] = "localhost";
                }
                //adding to my list of sites and it's corresponding Application Pool in 1 tuple variable
                siteInfo.Add((site, appPool, adrs[0] + ":" + adrs[1] + "/" + adrs[2])); //localhost:80/google.com 
            }
        }
    }
    return siteInfo;
}
```

I need something similar to this code: (see comments)

```
public List<(Site, ApplicationPool, string)> getSiteInfo()
{
    List<(Site, ApplicationPool, string)> siteInfo = new List<(Site, ApplicationPool, string)>();
    List<string> siteUrls = new List<string>();
    sites = serverMgr.Sites;
    foreach (Site site in sites)
    {
        foreach (Binding binding in site.Bindings)
        {
            //I need something like this to make sure the AppPool I'm getting is of the Site I have.
            ApplicationPool appPool = site.ApplicationPoolName;//<-- This Line
            string bindingInfo = binding.BindingInformation;
            string[] adrs = bindingInfo.Split(':');
            if (adrs[0] == "*")
            {
                adrs[0] = "localhost";
            }
            //So that I can do this when passing the Site Info tuple Variable with the Site Object together with the corresponding AppPool for later use of the IISReset Class in my project.
            siteInfo.Add((site, appPool, adrs[0] + ":" + adrs[1] + "/" + adrs[2]));
        }
    }
    return siteInfo;
}
```

Sorry for the long and sloppy explanation but I would be happy to clear out if you have questions with this. Thank you.

Comment: Only `Application` class has `ApplicationPool` property to tell which pool it belongs to. The `Site` class does not have that.

Comment: I see, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by using Applications attribute of a site. To get the application pool of a Site I did the code below. Where I got the list of applications of a site and used that to identify the app pool from the list of application pools in the server. However this only works if the site only has 1 application, that's why I'm indexing 0(zero) to get the first application (which is the only application of my site) to search for it's corresponding app pool.

```
ApplicationCollection apps = site.Applications;
ApplicationPool appPool = serverMgr.ApplicationPools[appname[0].ApplicationPoolName];
```